# Why would I get a 503 Service Unavailable error on Production when it works fine on local and has been working on production?

Tags: node.js, http, axios, http-headers

This has been working on Production for about 6 months now and suddenly it has stopped working.

I want to allow users to search for their Pro Club on Fifa. There is no API so I am hitting their URL and getting the data.

This is the URL: https://proclubs.ea.com/api/fifa/clubs/search?platform=ps4&clubName=cat

On local it responds with a 200 code but on Production it returns a 503 Service Unavailable error

Does anyone have any advice as to how to troubleshoot? I am wondering if I am missing a header but what is strange is it has been working for so long. Is it possible EA have blocked me?

Here is my code:

```
const eaClubsAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://proclubs.ea.com/api/fifa/clubs/search?platform=${platform}&clubName=${searchterm}`,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer': 'https://www.ea.com/'
    },
});

const getEaClubs = async () => {
    const eaClubs = await eaClubsAxios.get('');
    console.log({ eaClubs })
    return eaClubs.data;
};
```

Here is the console log of "eaClubs" from local:

```
{
     status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers: {
       'content-type': 'application/json',
       server: 'nginx',
       'referrer-policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
       'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
       'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
       'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
       'content-security-policy': "default-src 'self'",
       'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies': 'master-only',
       'cache-control': 'max-age=118',
       expires: 'Sun, 05 Dec 2021 15:07:11 GMT',
       date: 'Sun, 05 Dec 2021 15:05:13 GMT',
       'content-length': '45009',
       connection: 'close',
       'x-environment-context': 'prod',
       'x-application-context': 'proclubs',
       'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=86400',
       'set-cookie': [Array]
     },
     config: {
       adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
       transformRequest: [Object],
       transformResponse: [Object],
       timeout: 0,
       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
       maxContentLength: -1,
       validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
       headers: [Object],
       method: 'get',
       baseURL: 'https://proclubs.ea.com/api/fifa/clubs/search?platform=ps4&clubName=cat',
       url: 'https://proclubs.ea.com/api/fifa/clubs/search?platform=ps4&clubName=cat',
       data: undefined
     },
     request: ClientRequest {
       _events: [Object: null prototype],
       _eventsCount: 6,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       outputData: [],
       outputSize: 0,
       writable: true,
       destroyed: false,
       _last: true,
       chunkedEncoding: false,
       shouldKeepAlive: false,
       _defaultKeepAlive: true,
       useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
       sendDate: false,
       _removedConnection: false,
       _removedContLen: false,
       _removedTE: false,
       _contentLength: 0,
       _hasBody: true,
       _trailer: '',
       finished: true,
       _headerSent: true,
       socket: [TLSSocket],
       _header: 'GET /api/fifa/clubs/search?platform=ps4&clubName=cat HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
         'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
         'Referer: https://www.ea.com/\r\n' +
         'User-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\n' +
         'Host: proclubs.ea.com\r\n' +
         'Connection: close\r\n' +
         '\r\n',
       _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
       _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
       agent: [Agent],
       socketPath: undefined,
       method: 'GET',
       maxHeaderSize: undefined,
       insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
       path: '/api/fifa/clubs/search?platform=ps4&clubName=cat',
       _ended: true,
       res: [IncomingMessage],
       aborted: false,
       timeoutCb: null,
       upgradeOrConnect: false,
       parser: null,
       maxHeadersCount: null,
       reusedSocket: false,
       host: 'proclubs.ea.com',
       protocol: 'https:',
       _redirectable: [Writable],
       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
       [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
     },
     data: {
       '111723': [Object]
     }
}
```